# Check whether any element in a list has an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to loop through a list of table cells and check if any has a particular event (for example `click`), and then execute the callback function?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can loop through table cells and execute the click function.

Comment: @Vega I think you answered his question :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `td` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method to loop and use the events data to get at the events you are looking for:

```
$("td").each(function () 
  {
    //Do you work here
  });
```

So, for the following HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
    <tr>  <td id="t1A">A     <td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>B  <td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>C  <td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>D <td></tr>
</table>

<table id="t2">
    <tr>  <td id="t2A">A     <td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>B  <td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>C  <td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>D <td></tr>
</table>
```

You can use the following:

```
$("#t1A").click(function () {
    alert("t1A click event");
});

$("td").each(function () {
    var events = $._data(this, "events")

    if (!events) return;

    var clickEvents = events.click;

    if (!clickEvents) return;    

    if (clickEvents.length > 0) {
        alert($(this).attr("id") + " has a click event");
        $(this).click();   // Execute the click if you so desire.
    }
});
```

See this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdnr6/1/

Comment: Assuming that OP has only one table

Comment: @Saju This would work for all table cells.  If he wanted to limit it to a specific table, he could do that with a different selector.